Why are the federal, provincial and local political systems in Canada so much more separate than in other comparable systems?

American politics has seen a decline in split ticket voting
British politics is only introducing federalism now

London
UK Parliament elections in London

London Assembly elections

3. Australia
2022 State election in Victoria

2022 Australian Federal election in Victoria

In comparison, Canada has completely different parties in the provinces and the Canadian federal parliament. For example the Saskatchewan Party, BC United do not contest Canadian federal elections, the New Democratic Party is a main party in several provinces even in places where the same province elects federal Liberal MPs, and where the provincial Liberal party essentially does not exist.
Canadian provincial parties and federal parties are much more disconnected too.
Why do Canadian voters have such a unique separation between regional politics and national politics?
